# Ruby on Rails CRUD and Association example

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, crud

I am beginner on rails. I want to list Brands-Products list. Brands and products must be association. I dont know what to do. Please suggest me example like this.

Comment: Your question is very board. I suggest reading the [Rails Guides about Associations](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) and ask more a more specific question after reading when something is still unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

model brand.rb needs code:

`class Brand < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :products
end`

and product.rb

`class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :brand
end`

all the products belongs to any of one brand and each brand has many products.

Comment: thanks. but i dont know how can i create model in terminal and how can i take it from the textarea or something like that. also how can i show them.

Comment: Please go through Rails guides + follow one of many tutorials which can guide you how to create models, setup associations and views etc. Happy coding !

Comment: please refer this link [https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_model_basics.html] to know about models. to generate a model for product from terminal do `rails g model product`

Answer (score 0):

Just run this command on CMD for brand model:

```
rails g model brand sample_brand_field:data_type
```

After that for product model

```
rails g model product sample_product_field:data_type references:brand
```

And last step is to run migration

```
rake db:migrate
```